# Number Format Exception Card Game

Tags: java, image, exception, javafx, number-formatting

I have code for a game I have created here. It compiles fine, but when I run it I get a Number Format exception. I think it has something to do with my  int express = Integer.parseInt(str); line but I'm not sure. Could someone help point me in the right direction?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Main extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

      ArrayList<Integer> deck;
      deck = new ArrayList<>();
      int i = 1;
      while(i < 52){
         deck.add(i);
         i++;
      }
      final AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>("go.");

      Collections.shuffle(deck);

      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

      HBox top = new HBox(10);
      Label display = new Label(result.toString());
      Button btShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");
      btShuffle.setOnAction(
            e -> {
               Collections.shuffle(deck);
            });
      top.getChildren().add(display);
      top.getChildren().add(btShuffle);

      HBox center = new HBox(10);
      Card card1 = new Card(deck.get(0));
      center.getChildren().add(card1);

      Card card2 = new Card(deck.get(1));
      center.getChildren().add(card2);

      Card card3 = new Card(deck.get(2));
      center.getChildren().add(card3);

      Card card4 = new Card(deck.get(3));
      center.getChildren().add(card4);

      HBox bottom = new HBox(10);
      Label expression = new Label("Please Enter the expression: ");

      bottom.getChildren().addAll(expression);

      TextField tfExpress = new TextField();
      LinkedList<Object> expInput = new LinkedList<>();
      ArrayList<Character> signs = new ArrayList<>();
      signs.add('/');
      signs.add('+');
      signs.add('(');
      signs.add(')');
      signs.add('-');
      signs.add('^');
      signs.add('*');
      signs.add('%');
      String str = tfExpress.getText();
      char tempStor[] = str.toCharArray();
      for(char c: tempStor)
      {
         expInput.add(c);
      }
      int express = Integer.parseInt(str);


      expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));

      Button btVerify = new Button("Verify");
      btVerify.setOnAction(
            (ActionEvent e) -> {
               if(card1.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(0)
               && card2.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(1)
               && card3.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(2)
               && card4.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(3)){
                  if(express == 24){
                     result.set("Correct");
                  }
                  else
                     result.set("Incorrect");
               }
               else
                  result.set("The numbers in the expression don't "
                     + "match the numbers in the set.");
            });

      pane.setTop(top);
      pane.setCenter(center);
      pane.setBottom(bottom);

      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      primaryStage.setTitle("24 card game");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public class Card extends Pane 
   {
      public int cardVal;
      Card(int card)
      {
         Image cardImage;
         cardImage = new Image("card/"+ card +".png");
         cardVal = card;
      }

      public int CardValue()
      {
         int card = 0;

         if(cardVal <= 13)
         {
            card = cardVal;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 13 && cardVal <= 26)
         {
            card = cardVal - 13;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 26 && cardVal <= 39){
            card = cardVal - 26;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 39 && cardVal <= 52){
            card = cardVal - 39;
         }


         return card;
      }



   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Application.launch(args);
   }

}
```

Here's the exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Main.start(Main.java:81)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
```

Comment: `tfExpress` is empty...

Comment: what would I fill it with?

Comment: Don't parse the value it contains until there is a value present...

Comment: so just remove parse all together?

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate the TextField "tfExpress" just few line before getting get text and parse it. You should check if it's not null or empty before try to parse it.

Comment: could I use an if statement for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
int express = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Check the str is null or not before parsing. Whenever null/characters apart from numbers received  to convert into Integer then NumberFormatException will thrown by JVM. Either surround with Try,Catch block to avoid abnormal termination.

Comment: I tried doing if(tfExpress != null) around this statement and now it can't find express when I use it elsewhere. Is there a better place to put this?

Comment: try to sysout the variable value for debugging so that you will know what value it is passing if it is passing empty string then it is not equal to null so we  have to do something like this if(str.equals("")==false){// do parsing}